# Access parameter query empty/non-existent recordset

Tags: ms-access

I have a Crosstab parameter query (XQryOxPara) that gets its parameter value from a combo box (CBglaze) in a form (FrmGlazes)

This parameter query serves as the record source for another form (FrmGlazes2). This second form is placed on the first and whenever a new glaze is selected in FrmGlazes, FrmGlazes2 updates. It works fine most of the time

TblGlazes has a gid(primary key auto number), glaze(text), 31 other numeric fields which contain values of glaze ingredients. There is one record for each glaze.

TblOxides has oid(primary key, auto number), gid, glaze, subglaze(text which identifies the subglaze name), 16 other numeric fields which contain values for oxide ingredients of each glaze. There are multiple records for each glaze.

My questions relate to:

1. There are records (glazes) in TblGlazes (recordsource for CBglaze) that are not in the query source data (Union Query based on TblOxides).i.e. there are glazes that don't have any oxides in them. So there's no record for them in TblOxides. So if I choose one of these glazes from the combo box, the query doesn't show any records because there isn't a match in the query dataset which you'd expect.

e.g If I select bg1_more_alumina that is in TblGlazes but not TblOxides the resultant query datasheet view is empty. 
However, If i select bg1 (in both TblGlazes and TblOxides), it pulls in the right info.

2. When I look at the recordset for one of these "non-query" glazes (like bg1_more_alumina), it doesn't show up as empty but it doesn't show up as having records either.

What I'd like to do is format FrmGlazes2 to be blank if no records show up when a glaze is selected in FrmGlazes. But since the recordset is not showing as empty, I'm unable to write code for that instance. So if I use the code below from the On current event, I don't get either message box popping up. It just doesn't run. But it does run for the other instances and shows me all the relevant info

This is placed in the On_Current event for the subform:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()


    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim ColCount As Integer
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim frm2 As Form
    Dim arr1() As Variant
    Dim arr2() As Variant
    Dim coltot As Single
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim ctlname As String
    Dim ctl As Control


    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set frm = Forms!FrmGlazes
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs!XQryOxPara

    qdf.Parameters("Forms!FrmGlazes!Cbglaze") = frm![Cbglaze]          'Must go before set rst statement
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()


'   Hiding records based on whether values exist in field
'   ------------------------------------------------------
    If rst.EOF Then GoTo ErrNoRecords

    ReDim Preserve arr1(0 To 0)
    ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To 0)


    With rst
        Do Until .EOF
            For Each fld In .Fields
                If fld.Name <> "glaze" And fld.Name <> "Oxide" Then
                    J = fld.OrdinalPosition - 2
                    Debug.Print "val of J is: " & J & "Field Name: " & fld.Name
                    arr1(J) = arr1(J) + Nz(.Fields(fld.Name).Value)
                    arr2(J) = fld.Name
                    ReDim Preserve arr1(UBound(arr1) + 1)
                    ReDim Preserve arr2(UBound(arr2) + 1)
                    Debug.Print "arr1 value is: " & arr1(J)
                End If
            Next fld
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With



    ReDim Preserve arr1(UBound(arr1) - 1)
    ReDim Preserve arr2(UBound(arr2) - 1)

    Debug.Print "ub arr1 & arr2 are: " & UBound(arr1) & vbTab & UBound(arr2)


    For I = 0 To J
        ctlname = "Ctl" & arr2(I)
        Me.Controls(ctlname).ColumnHidden = 1
        Debug.Print "Ctlname is: " & ctlname & "arr1 value is: " & arr1(I)
        If arr1(I) = 0 Then
            Me.Controls(ctlname).ColumnHidden = -1
        ElseIf arr1(I) > 0 Then
            Me.Controls(ctlname).ColumnHidden = 0
        End If
    Next I





    qdf.Close
    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

    Exit Sub



ErrNoRecords:

    qdf.Close
    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing


End Sub
```

My code for my query is below:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![FrmGlazes]![Cbglaze] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM Max(QryOx.Oxvalue) AS MaxOfOxvalue
SELECT QryOx.glaze, QryOx.Oxide
FROM QryOx
WHERE ((QryOx.glaze)=[Forms]![FrmGlazes]![Cbglaze]) OR (([Forms]![FrmGlazes]![Cbglaze]) Is Null) 
GROUP BY QryOx.glaze, QryOx.Oxide
ORDER BY QryOx.glaze DESC 
PIVOT QryOx.subglaze In ("30","30_21","30_22","30_23","302");
```

Here's the code for qryOx

```
SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "cobalt" As Oxide, cobalt As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where cobalt Is Not Null And cobalt>0 
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "copper" As Oxide, copper As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where copper Is Not Null And copper>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "cocarb" As Oxide, cocarb As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where cocarb Is Not Null And cocarb>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "cucarb" As Oxide, cucarb As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where cucarb Is Not Null And cucarb>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "grilmenite" As Oxide, grilmenite As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where grilmenite Is Not Null And grilmenite>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "ilmenite" As Oxide, ilmenite As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where ilmenite Is Not Null And ilmenite>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "mio" As Oxide, mio As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where mio Is Not Null And mio>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "mndiox" As Oxide, mndiox As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where mndiox Is Not Null And mndiox>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "nickel" As Oxide, nickel As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where nickel Is Not Null And nickel>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "rio" As Oxide, rio As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where rio Is Not Null And rio>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "rutile" As Oxide, rutile As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where rutile Is Not Null And rutile>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "titdiox" As Oxide, titdiox As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where titdiox Is Not Null And titdiox>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "tin" As Oxide, tin As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where tin Is Not Null And tin>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "yio" As Oxide, yio As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where yio Is Not Null And yio>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "yochre" As Oxide, yochre As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where yochre Is Not Null And yochre>0
Order By glaze
UNION ALL SELECT TblOxides.subglaze, "zircon" As Oxide, zircon As Oxvalue, TblOxides.glaze, TblOxides.gid
From TblOxides
Where zircon Is Not Null And zircon>0
ORDER BY glaze;
```

Comment: Please provide enough information for us to be able to form an answer. What is exactly in that error? What is the table structure of both underlying tables? Give an example record for both a record that does work, and one that doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited it to make it a bit clearer (I hope) but I'm happy to answer more questions. Thanks for your interest

Comment: I'm still missing table structures, a record that does work, and one that doesn't work. With this information, I can't replicate your problem. See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some help asking questions.

Comment: Added table structure, and an example of a record that does and doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the real problem lies in `QryOx`. I don't know the code behind it, but it probably uses an `INNER JOIN`, which possibly should be a `LEFT JOIN`. I know I asked a lot, but I think we need the code from `QryOx` too to solve this.

Comment: Oh no worries, I'm happy somebody is taking a look at it. So questions are welcome. You may be on to something so QryOx has been posted

Comment: Ah, I understand your situation now, somewhat more difficult than I expected. But what exactly do you mean with `since the recordset is not showing as empty, I'm unable to write code for that instance`? That sounds like something I can help you with. `Recordset.RecordCount` tends to be inaccurate in those situations, but usually you can check `RecordSet.BOF AND RecordSet.EOF`

Comment: What I have is the following: 
If Not (rst.EOF = True And rst.BOF = True) Then
        MsgBox "records exist"
Else
        MsgBox "no records"
        GoTo ErrNoRecords
    End If

But I don't get the "no records" msgbox popping up and I don't get the "records exist" one either. It's not showing anything from the recordset for those cases. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please paste that in your question, including when you're calling that?  (you will probably need to call it from the main form, as the sub doesn't always trigger a current when it doesn't have a record)

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code and where I'm calling it from. I'll try calling it from the main form and see if that works. thanks

Comment: Please share the entire piece of code. How are you setting `rs`, are you calling it in the `Form_Current` from the main form (FrmGlazes) or from the subform (FrmGlazes2)?

Comment: You were right, I changed the code to be called from Form_current for the main form (FrmGlazes) instead of the subform(FrmGlazes2) and it worked correctly, showing "no records". Thank you!! If you still need the code, I can post it

Comment: Well, you can just answer the question yourself then. But please answer it, to show this problem has been solved.

Comment: But the solution came from you, so I'd like to credit you somehow. It wasn't from me. I'll post the code but if you post showing that I need to post it to the mainform and not the subform, I'll select that as the right answer. Thank you so much. I've been struggling with this for days literally.

Comment: Nah, you deserve the answer yourself, as you've figured it out too. Me copy-pasting your answer as mine would feel weird, and it's nice if the answer includes the full code. I'm just glad I could help

Comment: But the solution was not the code but the location of where it's placed. So you did provide the solution. Thanks again and my offer to select your answer as correct is still available. Many thanks again